# How to print output of a for loop in a single line in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, reverse

```
echo -n "input: "
while read line 
do 
   array=("${array[@]}" $line)
done
len=${#array[@]}

echo -n "Output:"
for (( n=0; n<=len; n++ ))
    do 
    echo "${array[n]}" | rev
done
```

I want the reversed output to be in a single line.

[image: Gratuitous screen shot]

Comment: `array+=( "$line" )` to append a line to an array more tersely and efficiently.

Comment: And `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` to just print the whole array at once as one line of code (with multiple lines of output), or `printf '%s ' "${array[@]}"; echo` to print it to one line of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using a reverse loop?

```sh
sep="" # no separator before first entry
for ((n=len; n>=0; n--))
do 
    printf "%s%s" "$sep" "${array[n]}"
    sep=" "
done
printf '\n'
```

Generally prefer `printf` over `echo -n`, though both would work here.

Or if you just want the output to be reversed character by character;

```sh
echo "${array[@]}" | rev
```

But then why do you need an array at all?

```sh
read -r -p 'input: '
echo "$REPLY" | rev
```